# Create excel file from domain model object - where should this code go?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, domain-model

I have a dashboard with many tables that I need to be able to export to excel. Each table is based on a domain model object collection from my domain model.

I have written some code that will take the collection and create an excel file from the data it contains.

Where does this code go? As a first pass, I just stuck it in my controller method. Once I create the excel file I return that in the controller. Easy, but clearly that's no good. But I can't imagine this goes in my domain either.

Where should this code go? I can't seem to classify it as controller logic, domain logic, or anything else. I'm basically serializing a domain object into data in an excel file and returning that to the client.

Eventually what I would like to do is have this code grab the data as json from a url and serialize that into an excel file. Again, I have no idea where that code should go either.